# Moment generating function of sum of $N$ exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, moment-generating-functions

We consider i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$, with $X_i\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda),$ and further independent variable $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$. Let $Y = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. Determine the moment generating function $\phi_Y(t) = E(e^{tY})$.

**My question**
I know that I can calculate the moment generating function by calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}f_Y(x)dx.$ However, the $N\sim \text{Poisson}(\mu),$ so I can't just say that $f_Y \sim \text{Gamma}(n, \lambda)$ (I thought this was the distribution of the sum of $N=n$ i.i.d. exponential variables)?
Any thoughts on how I need to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

$Ee^{tY}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }Ee^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i} P\{N=n\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(Ee^{tX_1})^{n} P\{N=n\}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Isn't $E(e^{tY}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i} P(N=n)$? Or do I need to include the $\mathbb{E}$ in the sum as well?

Comment: Without the expectation you would get a random variable. You are suppose to get a number, right?

Comment: Yes, true. I'm sorry but I still find it hard to compute this. The way my book states the moment generating function $E[e^{tY}] = \sum_y e^{ty}p(y)$

Comment: Yes, compute $Ee^{tX_1}$ using the your formula you have stated in the question (in as an integral)  $Ee^{tX_1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$; then  write down $P\{N=n\}$ and sum the series. The answer is $e^{\frac {\mu t} {\lambda - t}}$